# Why doesn't this event tracker work?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, onclick, google-analytics

I'm trying to record the url of a page when a user clicks a submit button using google analytics event trackers.

I have found a javascript function that should do the job but i cannot get it to work. Any suggestions?

I have dropped this is the  underneath the google analytic s snippit.

```
function recordOutboundLink(link, category, action) {  
    try {  
        var myTracker=_gat._getTrackerByName();  
        _gaq.push(['myTracker._trackEvent', ' + category + ', ' + action + ']);  
        setTimeout('document.location = "' + link.href + '"', 100)  
    }catch(err){}  
}
```

And Added this to the sumbit button.

```
<a href="/confirmation.html" onClick="recordOutboundLink(this, 'Outbound Links', 'example.com'); return false;">
```

but google anayltics isn't recording anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several problems with the `_trackEvent` call -- The syntax for the async version should be

```
`_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', category, action]);`
```

Also, it looks like you're mixing old style analytics code with with async style code -- you don't need to use `_getTrackerByName` in this case.

Try the following version:

```
function recordOutboundLink(link, category, action) {  
    try {  
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', category, action]);
        setTimeout('document.location = "' + link.href + '"', 100)  
    }catch(err){}  
}
```